# How to use DwmRegisterThumbnail with child windows?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm 'casting' the screen of `window1` to `window2` using the WINAPI [DwmRegisterThumbnail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmregisterthumbnail)

but as soon I set the `window2` child of another window the image `disappears`.

After reading the docs I found this mention:

> Setting the destination window handle to anything other than a
> top-level window type will result in a return value of E_INVALIDARG.

```
    HWND dest = (HWND)this->winId();
    HWND source = ...
    hr = DwmRegisterThumbnail(dest, source, &thumbnail_id);
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    qDebug() << "hr: " << hr;

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && NULL != thumbnail_id)
    {
        prop.dwFlags = DWM_TNP_RECTDESTINATION | DWM_TNP_RECTSOURCE | DWM_TNP_OPACITY
            | DWM_TNP_VISIBLE | DWM_TNP_SOURCECLIENTAREAONLY;
        prop.rcSource = { 0, 0, 1200, 600 };
        prop.rcDestination = { 0, 0, 1200, 600 };
        prop.opacity = 255;
        prop.fVisible = TRUE;
        prop.fSourceClientAreaOnly = FALSE;

        hr = DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties(thumbnail_id, &prop);

        qDebug() << "hr: " << hr;
    }
```

I also tried using a [QDockWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdockwidget.html) but the image is visible only when the widget is not docked to the `MainWindow`, as soon I dock the widget, the image disappears, sad.

There's something else I could try to be able to 'cast' the image to a child window?

or maybe another winapi I could use?

Comment: Not supported. You can use a top-level owned window so that it always appears above a given window. You have to update its position whenever the owner window moves.

Comment: NO such documented API. Even [DwmRegisterThumbnail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmregisterthumbnail) already states *Setting the destination window handle to anything other than a top-level window type will result in a return value of E_INVALIDARG*.